# Changing dns server address at router

Tags: router, dns, modem

I have a cable modem+router (let's call it A) and an RJ-45 cat 6 cable which originates from A and goes to another router (B). Most of my wifi enabled devices use B's wifi netowrk. I want to change to a specific DNS server for all my dns queries that come at B, from the default DNS service provided by my ISP. So, should I change the dns settings of router A or B in order to achieve this? In addition to this, I have explored all the possible settings of A and the default dns address in A's settings seems unchangeable. The main cable from my ISP comes in router A.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the DHCP setup on both your routers.

Normally, when a client connects to wifi, it gets the address of its DNS server from a DHCP server (at the same time it gets its IP address).  In a network like yours with two routers, typically you would only run one DHCP server.  However, this could be on either router.  It's also possible that you have DHCP servers enabled on both routers.  With two DHCP servers running, a client could potentially connect to either one, regardless of which router's wifi it is linked to.

In Windows, you can see which DHCP server a client used by typing `ipconfig /all` at the command prompt.  This will also show which DNS server the client is using.

You need to make sure that the router running the DHCP server is set up with the right DNS address.  If you really can't change the DNS setting on router A, you might be able to disable its DHCP server, and just use the DHCP server on router B instead.    Before doing this, make sure you note down how the DHCP server on router A was configured, so you can set up router B the same way.

Also be aware that you might have some clients that don't use the DNS address supplied by DHCP: either ones that have static IP addresses and don't use DHCP at all, or ones that have been configured to over-ride the address given to them by the server.

Comment: I tried following out the procedure you mentioned. There is one device which has to use router A, and the command prompt showed it as connected to A. So I cannot disable DHCP on A as then that device won't be able to access Internet. Also, before reading your answer, I managed a workaround in which I changed B's dns settings. And currently there is only one device using A, so I manually overrode that device's dns settings. As of now I have performed dns leak tests from devices using both A and B and everything seems to be working as intended.

Comment: Glad you found a workaround. However, you ought to be able to disable the DHCP on Router A anyway.  As the routers are linked, DHCP requests should get passed on to Router B.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But disabling DHCP on A and removing the manual override on device using A is leading to DNS leaks on the device. Guess I'll have to stick with the workaround for now.

Answer (score 0):

If your devices are connected to router B, then changing the DNS entries there will change the DNS on all devices connecting to that router.  This is assuming the devices are are set up to get DNS from the router, which they would be if they are set to DHCP.

As for your ISPs router, without knowing the make and model, no one can tell you if the DNS is changeable.  Additionally, the ISP may have made that setting unchangeable.

If you arent using the ISPs for anything other than the modem, it may be possible to disable the router functionality altogether, leaving it is purely a modem.

Comment: A here is Changhong DOCSIS 3.0 Wireless Cable Modem, Product Model CM500 UW1. And B is D-link DIR-816 AC750 router. I was unable to find any documentation about A on the internet. And this is how the dns settings on A look like:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!Av2QEU7cggC1lGQMYPVk9fRWgl7C       Also, is there any way to verify after applying settings that the queries are indeed going to the intended router only?